# Not able to run custom module

Tags: ansible, vagrant, ansible-module

I created a custom module called `pingtest` which pings all the server using the `ping` command. I have created a shell script for that and later placed it inside the library directory of the playbook directory. When I wrote a playbook to use that module it gives me an error saying

```
" fatal: [ansibleclient]: FAILED! => {"msg": "module (pingtest) is missing interpreter line"}"
```

I tried to make changes in IP address but nothing seems to be working and I am using Ansible version 2.7.9.

The `pingtest` module:

```bash
#/bin/bash /bin/sh
 source $1 >/home/vagrant/ping.out>&1

 TARGET=${target:-127.0.0.1}
ping -c 1 ${TARGET} >/home/vagrant/ping.out 2>/home/vagrant/ping.err

if [ $? == 0 ];
then
echo "{\"changed\": true, \"rc\": 0}"
else
  echo "{\"failed\": true, \"msg\": \"failed to ping\", \"rc\": 1}"
fi
```

The playbook to use `pingtest` module:

```yaml
---
- hosts: linux
  tasks:
  - name: Calling pingtest module
    pingtest:
      target: 192.168.111.31
```

I expected that module will run but don't know why I am getting below error

```
fatal: [ansibleclient]: FAILED! => {"msg": "module (pingtest) is missing interpreter line"}
fatal: [ubuntuclient]: FAILED! => {"msg": "module (pingtest) is missing interpreter line"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first line in your pingtest module is invalid.

Change to `#!/bin/bash` and it should work just fine.